Flutter Custom Painter not Repainting
I am trying to get familiar with CustomPainters in Flutter, and tried to use a custom painter to draw a barrier with a cutout around a specific widget over the screen, to behave like a tutorial.
I have a stack with a custom painter and I'm using overlays to overlay a tutorial barrier over the main page. My thought was to have a list of widgets to highlight, with the "tutorial" walking the user widget-by-widget as they click-through, with the painter redrawing to highlight the next target widget or dismissing on the last.
Unfortunately, the custom painter only paints the first variation, and then disappears*. I can confirm through debugPrint statements that the painter is receiving updated bounds, but it just isn't repainting properly (this is true with/without overriding the == and hashCode defs and whether or not shouldRepaint is always set to true or has additional logic within).
]
*On dartpad.dev, the painter doesn't render at all, even the first one.
I've also tried giving keys to the Stack, the Positioned, and the CustomPaint widgets - no change.
In debug mode, if I set a breakpoint in the paint function of my HolePainter, after hitting play on each repaint and returning to the app, it behaves as expected.

I'm looking for some help in understanding why the painter isn't re-rendering...
What am I missing in the documentation? Is there a known trick to prompt the expected behavior?
Thank you in advance.
My code snippet:
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: DebugPageTutorial(),
    );
  }
}

class DebugPageTutorial extends StatefulWidget {
  const DebugPageTutorial({super.key});

  @override
  State<DebugPageTutorial> createState() => _DebugPageTutorialState();
}

class _DebugPageTutorialState extends State<DebugPageTutorial> {
  final GlobalKey _overlayKey1 = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey _overlayKey2 = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey _overlayKey3 = GlobalKey();

  OverlayEntry? currentOverlayEntry;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    currentOverlayEntry = null;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _onTutorialFinished();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _onTutorialFinished() {
    if (currentOverlayEntry?.mounted ?? false) currentOverlayEntry?.remove();
    currentOverlayEntry = null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                key: _overlayKey1,
                'This is a tutorial page',
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 24,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                key: _overlayKey2,
                'This is a tutorial page',
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
                child: Container(
                  key: _overlayKey3,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: Colors.cyan,
                  ),
                  height: 50.0,
                  width: 50.0,
                ),
              ),
              MaterialButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  currentOverlayEntry = TutorialOverlay.createOverlayEntry(
                    context,
                    overlayKeys: [
                      TutorialOverlayTooltip(
                        overlayKey: _overlayKey1,
                        overlayTooltip: const Text('Hello'),
                      ),
                      TutorialOverlayTooltip(
                        overlayKey: _overlayKey2,
                        overlayTooltip: const Text('World'),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        shapeBorder: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(
                              8.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        color: Colors.green,
                      ),
                      TutorialOverlayTooltip(
                          overlayKey: _overlayKey3,
                          overlayTooltip: const Text('Beep'),
                          shapeBorder: CircleBorder(),
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                          color: Colors.red),
                      TutorialOverlayTooltip(
                        overlayKey: _overlayKey1,
                        overlayTooltip: const Text('Bop'),
                      ),
                    ],
                    onTutorialFinished: _onTutorialFinished,
                  );
                  Overlay.of(context).insert(currentOverlayEntry!);
                },
                child: const Text('Show Tutorial'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
}

class TutorialOverlay extends StatefulWidget {
  /// A list of keys and overlay tooltips to display when the overlay is
  /// displayed. The overlay will be displayed in the order of the list.
  final List<TutorialOverlayTooltip> overlayKeys;

  /// A global key to use as the ancestor for the overlay entry, ensuring that
  /// the overlay entry is not shifted improperly when the overlay is only being
  /// painted on a portion of the screen. If null, the overlay will be painted
  /// based on the heuristics of the entire screen.
  final GlobalKey? ancestorKey;

  final FutureOr<void> Function()? onTutorialFinished;

  const TutorialOverlay({
    super.key,
    required this.overlayKeys,
    this.ancestorKey,
    this.onTutorialFinished,
  });

  static OverlayEntry createOverlayEntry(
    BuildContext context, {
    required List<TutorialOverlayTooltip> overlayKeys,
    GlobalKey? ancestorKey,
    FutureOr<void> Function()? onTutorialFinished,
  }) =>
      OverlayEntry(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => TutorialOverlay(
          overlayKeys: overlayKeys,
          ancestorKey: ancestorKey,
          onTutorialFinished: onTutorialFinished,
        ),
      );

  @override
  State<TutorialOverlay> createState() => _TutorialOverlayState();
}

class _TutorialOverlayState extends State<TutorialOverlay> {
  late List<TutorialOverlayTooltip> _overlayKeys;
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  TutorialOverlayTooltip? get _currentTooltip =>
      _currentIndex < _overlayKeys.length ? _overlayKeys[_currentIndex] : null;
  final ValueNotifier<int> _repaintKey = ValueNotifier<int>(0);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _overlayKeys = widget.overlayKeys;
  }

  Rect? _getNextRenderBox(GlobalKey? key) {
    final RenderBox? renderBox =
        key?.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox?;
    if (renderBox != null && renderBox.hasSize) {
      final Offset offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(
        Offset.zero,
        ancestor: widget.ancestorKey?.currentContext?.findRenderObject(),
      );
      return Rect.fromLTWH(
        offset.dx,
        offset.dy,
        renderBox.size.width,
        renderBox.size.height,
      );
    }
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Rect? nextRenderBox = _getNextRenderBox(_currentTooltip?.overlayKey);
    if (nextRenderBox == null) return const SizedBox();

    // Determine position for the tutorial text
    double textTop = nextRenderBox.top > 100
        ? nextRenderBox.top - 40
        : nextRenderBox.bottom + 20;

    debugPrint('build: ${nextRenderBox.toString()}');

    return Stack(
      children: [
        // Paint the background
        Positioned.fill(
          key: ValueKey('tutorial_paint:$_currentIndex'),
          left: 0.0,
          right: 0.0,
          top: 0.0,
          bottom: 0.0,
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: HolePainter(
              repaint: _repaintKey,
              targetRect: nextRenderBox,
              shapeBorder: _currentTooltip?.shapeBorder ??
                  const RoundedRectangleBorder(),
              color: _currentTooltip?.color ?? const Color(0x90000000),
              direction: _currentTooltip?.direction ?? TextDirection.ltr,
              padding: _currentTooltip?.padding ?? EdgeInsets.zero,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        // Tutorial text box
        Positioned(
          top: textTop,
          left: nextRenderBox.left,
          child: Material(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              color: Colors.white,
              child: GestureDetector(
                behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                onTap: () {
                  if (_currentIndex + 1 < _overlayKeys.length) {
                    return setState(() {
                      _currentIndex = _currentIndex + 1;
                      _repaintKey.value = _currentIndex;
                    });
                  }
                  widget.onTutorialFinished?.call();
                },
                child: _currentTooltip?.overlayTooltip ?? const SizedBox(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

/// Contains information for drawing a tutorial overlay over a given widget
/// based on the provided global key.
class TutorialOverlayTooltip {
  /// The key of the widget to highlight in the cutout of the tutorial overlay
  final GlobalKey overlayKey;

  /// The widget to render by the cutout of the totorial overlay
  final Widget overlayTooltip;

  /// The padding around the widget to render by the cutout of the totorial
  /// overlay. Default is EdgeInsets.zero
  final EdgeInsets padding;

  /// The shape of the cutout of the totorial overlay. Default is a rounded
  /// rectangle with no border radius
  final ShapeBorder shapeBorder;

  /// The color of the barrier of the totorial overlay. Default is
  /// Black with 50% opacity
  final Color color;

  /// The direction of the cutout of the totorial overlay. Default is
  /// [TextDirection.ltr]
  final TextDirection direction;

  const TutorialOverlayTooltip({
    required this.overlayKey,
    required this.overlayTooltip,
    this.padding = EdgeInsets.zero,
    this.shapeBorder = const RoundedRectangleBorder(),
    this.color = const Color(0x90000000), // Black with 50% opacity
    this.direction = TextDirection.ltr,
  });
}

/// A painter that covers the area with a shaped hole around a target box
class HolePainter extends CustomPainter {
  /// The key of the widget to highlight in the cutout of the tutorial overlay
  final ValueNotifier? repaint;

  /// The target rect to paint a hole around
  final Rect targetRect;

  /// The padding around the target rect in the hole
  final EdgeInsets padding;

  /// The shape of the hole to paint around the target rect
  final ShapeBorder shapeBorder;

  /// The color of the barrier that the hole is cut from.
  final Color color;

  /// The direction of the hole. Default is [TextDirection.ltr]
  final TextDirection direction;

  const HolePainter({
    this.repaint,
    required this.targetRect,
    this.shapeBorder =
        const RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero),
    this.color = const Color(0x90000000), // Black with 50% opacity
    this.padding = EdgeInsets.zero,
    this.direction = TextDirection.ltr,
  }): super(repaint: repaint);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = color
      ..blendMode = BlendMode.dstOver;

    // Create a padded rectangle from the targetRect using padding
    final Rect paddedRect = Rect.fromLTRB(
      targetRect.left - padding.left,
      targetRect.top - padding.top,
      targetRect.right + padding.right,
      targetRect.bottom + padding.bottom,
    );

    // Create the background path covering the entire canvas
    Path backgroundPath = Path()
      ..addRect(
        Rect.fromLTWH(
          0,
          0,
          size.width,
          size.height,
        ),
      );

    // Create the hole path depending on the shapeBorder
    Path holePath = Path();
    if (shapeBorder is RoundedRectangleBorder) {
      BorderRadiusGeometry borderRadiusGeometry =
          (shapeBorder as RoundedRectangleBorder).borderRadius;
      BorderRadius borderRadius = borderRadiusGeometry.resolve(direction);
      holePath.addRRect(
        RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
          paddedRect,
          topLeft: borderRadius.topLeft,
          topRight: borderRadius.topRight,
          bottomLeft: borderRadius.bottomLeft,
          bottomRight: borderRadius.bottomRight,
        ),
      );
    } else if (shapeBorder is CircleBorder) {
      // Use the smaller side to ensure it fits within the padded rect
      double radius = paddedRect.width < paddedRect.height
          ? paddedRect.width / 2
          : paddedRect.height / 2;
      holePath.addOval(
        Rect.fromCircle(
          center: paddedRect.center,
          radius: radius,
        ),
      );
    } else {
      // Only support RoundedRectangleBorder and CircleBorder for now
      throw Exception('Unsupported shape border type');
    }

    // Combine the paths to create a cut-out effect
    Path combinedPath = Path.combine(
      PathOperation.difference,
      backgroundPath,
      holePath,
    );
    // Draw to the canvas
    canvas.drawPath(
      combinedPath,
      paint,
    );
    debugPrint('paint: ${targetRect.toString()}');
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    if (oldDelegate is HolePainter)
      debugPrint(
        'repaint: ${oldDelegate.targetRect.toString()} => ${targetRect.toString()}',
      );
    return true;
  }
}



"[...] but it just isn't repainting properly" - go to https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html and read the paragraph starting with: "The most efficient way to trigger a repaint is to either:"

Thanks! I'll give this more of a shot when I can. Also the link with the paragraph you've mentioned is actually: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html but I got there through your link and clicking around to the linked pages, so thank you all the same.

sure I meant CustomPainter, sorry for misleading...

I've now attempted both recommendations noted there and neither of them makes any difference. Not quite sure what the issue is here. It's all exactly the same code, but I added a repaint parameter to my CustomPainter class (and passed to super, of course), and updated the ValueNotifier when changing targets. No effect.

post the minimal, (not)working code then - i use repaint: ... very often and it works without any problems

I've added the main function that was missing. It now has everything it needs to be run in dartpad or in a new flutter project (sorry, I had thought I had posted it with that, I overlooked it apparently). -- I can't really cut too much out without altering the desired functionality. If it would be helpful I can try to gut the style-segments of the TutorialOverlayTooltip class. As-is though, it works on MacOS for the first paint, but not on web/dartpad at all, and and never on any platform for subsequent paints (Unless in debug mode with breakpoints, for some reason).

btw honestly you could achieve much much better user experience if you created a class that extends ImplicitlyAnimatedWidget - with that you could have a smooth, animated transitions between each step both with background color and shape of the hole - now you have sharp, abrupt "jumps"

True; for this I was just trying to understand the basics of how to go about implementing something like this- there's a ton of room for polish.

And thanks a ton! I see what you've changed. I am a tad bit confused why my way didn't work at all but yours works like a charm even on web, where mine wouldn't work on web at all. Clearly I'll need to dive deeper into this and really examine your approach, but now I have a clear example to dive into. -- If you want to chuck your gist in an answer comment I'll accept it so you get the rep. I appreciate you taking the time to take a look and explain this to me.

btw if you want to see the animations in slow motion find the line // timeDilation = 5 and uncomment it

I did! Thanks! I see what you're saying and follow your logic with the animations. I need to do some further investigation with some of the other features you used in the paint method as I noticed you used some additional functions that I didn't initially use that seem to have directly contributed to yours working where mine floundered. -- If I may ask; how did you learn/get experience with custom painter? I know the docs have a bunch of information; is it just that & trial and error, or are there other resourced that helped you out before it clicked? In any case, thanks a ton!

when it comes to ImplicitlyAnimatedWidget - the heart of the whole solution - i followed the sources (the best example is AnimatedContainer) - reading just docs of ImplicitlyAnimatedWidget is imho a waste of time ;-) btw does the animated version look better now? you can play with two other widgets i used: AnimatedSwitcher and AnimatedSize and change / remove them to get a different morphing of tooltips

update, i added optional alignment for a tooltip (default is top center), also using routes instead of overlays gives better UX imho (check my gist)

Based on @pskink's comments on the thread under the question:
The custom painter's expected behavior can be better accomplished by altering the painter method (no repaint listenable is needed) and setting state which will cause a repaint of the custom painter. Furthermore, by making use of an ImplicitlyAnimatedWidget, we were able to smooth the jank between the different paints.
Code below:
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: DebugPageTutorial(),
    );
  }
}

class DebugPageTutorial extends StatefulWidget {
  const DebugPageTutorial({super.key});

  @override
  State<DebugPageTutorial> createState() => _DebugPageTutorialState();
}

class _DebugPageTutorialState extends State<DebugPageTutorial> {
  final GlobalKey _overlayKey1 = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey _overlayKey2 = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey _overlayKey3 = GlobalKey();

  OverlayEntry? currentOverlayEntry;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    currentOverlayEntry = null;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _onTutorialFinished();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _onTutorialFinished() {
    if (currentOverlayEntry?.mounted ?? false) currentOverlayEntry?.remove();
    currentOverlayEntry = null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                key: _overlayKey1,
                'This is a tutorial page',
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 24,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                key: _overlayKey2,
                'This is a tutorial page',
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
                child: Container(
                  key: _overlayKey3,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: Colors.cyan,
                  ),
                  height: 50.0,
                  width: 50.0,
                ),
              ),
              MaterialButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  currentOverlayEntry = TutorialOverlay.createOverlayEntry(
                    context,
                    overlayKeys: [
                      TutorialOverlayTooltip(
                        overlayKey: _overlayKey1,
                        overlayTooltip: ConstrainedBox(
                          constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 150),
                          child: const Text('Excepteur irure exercitation consequat esse aute occaecat voluptate nulla minim.'),
                        ),
                        color: Colors.indigo.shade900.withOpacity(0.9),
                      ),
                      TutorialOverlayTooltip(
                        overlayKey: _overlayKey2,
                        overlayTooltip: ConstrainedBox(
                          constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 125),
                          child: const Text('Proident qui proident dolore dolor minim voluptate mollit dolore eiusmod nostrud nulla.'),
                        ),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
                        color: Colors.orange,
                      ),
                      TutorialOverlayTooltip(
                        overlayKey: _overlayKey3,
                        overlayTooltip: ConstrainedBox(
                          constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 150),
                          child: const Text('Sint elit officia non Lorem magna id.'),
                        ),
                        shape: const CircleBorder(),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
                        color: Colors.green.shade900.withOpacity(0.9),
                      ),
                    ],
                    onTutorialFinished: _onTutorialFinished,
                  );
                  Overlay.of(context).insert(currentOverlayEntry!);
                },
                child: const Text('Show Tutorial'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
}

class TutorialOverlay extends StatefulWidget {
  /// A list of keys and overlay tooltips to display when the overlay is
  /// displayed. The overlay will be displayed in the order of the list.
  final List<TutorialOverlayTooltip> overlayKeys;

  /// A global key to use as the ancestor for the overlay entry, ensuring that
  /// the overlay entry is not shifted improperly when the overlay is only being
  /// painted on a portion of the screen. If null, the overlay will be painted
  /// based on the heuristics of the entire screen.
  final GlobalKey? ancestorKey;

  final FutureOr<void> Function()? onTutorialFinished;

  const TutorialOverlay({
    super.key,
    required this.overlayKeys,
    this.ancestorKey,
    this.onTutorialFinished,
  });

  static OverlayEntry createOverlayEntry(
    BuildContext context, {
    required List<TutorialOverlayTooltip> overlayKeys,
    GlobalKey? ancestorKey,
    FutureOr<void> Function()? onTutorialFinished,
  }) =>
      OverlayEntry(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => TutorialOverlay(
          overlayKeys: overlayKeys,
          ancestorKey: ancestorKey,
          onTutorialFinished: onTutorialFinished,
        ),
      );

  @override
  State<TutorialOverlay> createState() => _TutorialOverlayState();
}

class _TutorialOverlayState extends State<TutorialOverlay> {
  late List<TutorialOverlayTooltip> _overlayKeys;
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  TutorialOverlayTooltip? get _currentTooltip =>
      _currentIndex < _overlayKeys.length ? _overlayKeys[_currentIndex] : null;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _overlayKeys = widget.overlayKeys;
  }

  Rect? _getNextRenderBox(GlobalKey? key) {
    final renderBox = key?.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox?;
    if (renderBox != null && renderBox.hasSize) {
      final Offset offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(
        Offset.zero,
        ancestor: widget.ancestorKey?.currentContext?.findRenderObject(),
      );
      return offset & renderBox.size;
    }
    return null;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Rect? nextRenderBox = _getNextRenderBox(_currentTooltip?.overlayKey);
    if (nextRenderBox == null) return const SizedBox();

    // debugPrint('build: ${nextRenderBox.toString()}');

    final tooltipColor = HSLColor.fromColor(_currentTooltip?.color ?? const Color(0x90000000));
    return AnimatedTutorial(
      duration: Durations.long2,
      targetRect: nextRenderBox,
      shape: _currentTooltip?.shape ?? const RoundedRectangleBorder(),
      color: _currentTooltip?.color ?? const Color(0x90000000),
      padding: _currentTooltip?.padding ?? EdgeInsets.zero,
      curve: Curves.ease,
      child: Material(
        color: tooltipColor.withAlpha(1).withLightness(0.75).toColor(),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
        elevation: 3,
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        child: InkWell(
          splashColor: Colors.white24,
          highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
          onTap: () {
            int newIndex = _currentIndex + 1;
            if(newIndex >= _overlayKeys.length) {
              widget.onTutorialFinished?.call();
              return;
            }
            setState(() => _currentIndex = newIndex);
          },
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: AnimatedSize(
              duration: Durations.medium2,
              curve: Curves.ease,
              child: AnimatedSwitcher(
                duration: Durations.medium2,
                child: KeyedSubtree(
                  key: UniqueKey(),
                  child: _currentTooltip?.overlayTooltip ?? const SizedBox(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// Contains information for drawing a tutorial overlay over a given widget
/// based on the provided global key.
class TutorialOverlayTooltip {
  /// The key of the widget to highlight in the cutout of the tutorial overlay
  final GlobalKey overlayKey;

  /// The widget to render by the cutout of the totorial overlay
  final Widget overlayTooltip;

  /// The padding around the widget to render by the cutout of the totorial
  /// overlay. Default is EdgeInsets.zero
  final EdgeInsets padding;

  /// The shape of the cutout of the totorial overlay. Default is a rounded
  /// rectangle with no border radius
  final ShapeBorder shape;

  /// The color of the barrier of the totorial overlay. Default is
  /// Black with 50% opacity
  final Color color;

  const TutorialOverlayTooltip({
    required this.overlayKey,
    required this.overlayTooltip,
    this.padding = EdgeInsets.zero,
    this.shape = const RoundedRectangleBorder(),
    this.color = const Color(0x90000000), // Black with 50% opacity
  });
}

class AnimatedTutorial extends ImplicitlyAnimatedWidget {
  AnimatedTutorial({
    super.key,
    required super.duration,
    required this.targetRect,
    required this.padding,
    required ShapeBorder shape,
    required Color color,
    required this.child,
    super.curve,
  }) : decoration = ShapeDecoration(shape: shape, color: color);

  final Rect targetRect;
  final EdgeInsets padding;
  final Decoration decoration;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  ImplicitlyAnimatedWidgetState<ImplicitlyAnimatedWidget> createState() {
    return _AnimatedTutorialState();
  }
}

class _AnimatedTutorialState extends AnimatedWidgetBaseState<AnimatedTutorial> {
  RectTween? _targetRect;
  EdgeInsetsGeometryTween? _padding;
  DecorationTween? _decoration;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // timeDilation = 5; // sloooow motion for testing
    return CustomPaint(
      painter: HolePainter(
        targetRect: _targetRect?.evaluate(animation) as Rect,
        decoration: _decoration?.evaluate(animation) as ShapeDecoration,
        direction: Directionality.of(context),
        padding: _padding?.evaluate(animation) as EdgeInsetsGeometry,
      ),
      child: CustomSingleChildLayout(
        delegate: TooltipDelegate(_targetRect?.evaluate(animation) as Rect),
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void forEachTween(TweenVisitor<dynamic> visitor) {
    _targetRect = visitor(_targetRect, widget.targetRect, (dynamic value) => RectTween(begin: value as Rect)) as RectTween?;
    _padding = visitor(_padding, widget.padding, (dynamic value) => EdgeInsetsGeometryTween(begin: value as EdgeInsetsGeometry)) as EdgeInsetsGeometryTween?;
    _decoration = visitor(_decoration, widget.decoration, (dynamic value) => DecorationTween(begin: value as Decoration)) as DecorationTween?;
  }
}

class TooltipDelegate extends SingleChildLayoutDelegate {
  TooltipDelegate(this.rect);

  final Rect rect;
  final padding = const Offset(0, 6);

  @override
  Offset getPositionForChild(Size size, Size childSize) {
    assert(size.width - childSize.width >= 0);
    assert(size.height - childSize.height >= 0);
    final position = rect.topLeft - childSize.bottomLeft(padding);
    return _clamp(position.dy >= 0? position : rect.bottomLeft, size, childSize);
  }

  Offset _clamp(Offset position, Size size, Size childSize) {
    return Offset(
      position.dx.clamp(0, size.width - childSize.width),
      position.dy.clamp(0, size.height - childSize.height),
    );
  }

  @override
  BoxConstraints getConstraintsForChild(BoxConstraints constraints) => constraints.loosen();

  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(covariant SingleChildLayoutDelegate oldDelegate) => true;
}

/// A painter that covers the area with a shaped hole around a target box
class HolePainter extends CustomPainter {
  const HolePainter({
    required this.targetRect,
    required this.decoration,
    required this.padding,
    this.direction = TextDirection.ltr,
  });

  /// The target rect to paint a hole around
  final Rect targetRect;

  /// The padding around the target rect in the hole
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry padding;

  /// The shape decoration of the hole to paint around the target rect
  final ShapeDecoration decoration;

  /// The direction of the hole. Default is [TextDirection.ltr]
  final TextDirection direction;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = decoration.color ?? Colors.transparent;

    final Rect paddedRect = padding.resolve(direction).inflateRect(targetRect);
    Path path = Path()
      ..fillType = PathFillType.evenOdd
      ..addRect(Offset.zero & size)
      ..addPath(decoration.getClipPath(paddedRect, direction), Offset.zero);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    // debugPrint('paint: ${targetRect.toString()}');
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}

The above code works across all platforms and exhibits none of the issues highlighted in the question. It is also available in a Gist at the link below:
Github Gist by pskink
